# Combine istream_iterator with regex_token_iterator

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Is it possible to combine an `istream_iterator` with an `regex_token_iterator` similar like this:

```
std::copy(
    std::sregex_token_iterator(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{ifs},
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}, r, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator{},
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout)
);
```

To give this a little bit of context. Im new to programming and im trying to solve a problem where i want to delete everything in an ifstream, except digits. Im doing this for practice and learning.

The input file is looking like this:

```
aoisdnf 2 aopsjmdf 4 anpoidsnian 5 ainsdf 12 paalknshndf 43 aoksjhndfal 4 aslkdfoo 9 hjalkgshgdfk 4
```

The solution should look like this:

```
2 4 5 12 43 4 9 4
```

My first approach was this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
   std::ifstream ifs ("C:/Users/../whitespace_seperated_integers.txt", std::ifstream::in);
   std::string tmp;
   std::vector<int> vector;

   for (auto it = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{ifs}; it != std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}; ++it) {
      if (*it >= '0' && *it <= '9') tmp.append(1, *it);
      else if (!tmp.empty()){
         vector.push_back(std::stoi(tmp));
         tmp.clear();
      }
   }
   if (!tmp.empty()) vector.push_back(std::stoi(tmp));

   for(const auto i : vector){
      std::cout << i << " ";
   }
```

Which worked fine, but then i had the idea to solve this problem with regex, which lead to this solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
   std::ifstream ifs ("C:/Users/../whitespace_seperated_integers.txt", std::ifstream::in);
   std::string puf;
   std::vector<std::string> vector;
   std::string line;
   char wts = ' ';
   while(getline(ifs ,line, wts)){
      puf += line;
   }
   std::regex r(R"([^\d]*(\d+))");
   std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(puf.begin(), puf.end(), r, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator(), std::back_inserter(vector));

   std::vector<int> vec;
   std::smatch sm;
   while(std::regex_search(puf, sm, r))
   {
      vec.push_back(std::stoi(sm[1]));
      /* std::cout << sm[1] << '\n';*/
      puf = sm.suffix();
   }
   for(const auto i : vec){
      std::cout << i << " ";
   }
}
```

But im not really happy with this code, so i was trying to figure out how to improve it. I tried to combine the istream_iterator with the regex_token_iterator, but im not able to figure out how it works.

Comment: There is a `regex_replace` method. See [demo](https://ideone.com/t6h1gD) (or [this one](https://ideone.com/Z3Gjxk))

Comment: `std::regex_token_iterator` requires to work over _bidirectional iterator_, so it cannot work over `std::istream_iterator`, whcih is _input iterator_ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use the `std::sregex_token_iterator`, then you may want to chose a different approach.

For your given string, you want to extract the number. We can change the vieving angle and used a different algorithm. If we do see everything that is NOT a digit as a delimiter, we can use the `std::sregex_token_iterator` with the index parameter -1 for splitting up the string.

So, the secret is the new delimiter. Then the result is a one-liner

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // The test string
    std::string test{"aoisdnf 2 aopsjmdf 4 anpoidsnian 5 ainsdf 12 paalknshndf 43 aoksjhndfal 4 aslkdfoo 9 hjalkgshgdfk 4"};

    // regex for anything but a digit
    const std::regex re {R"([\D]+)"};

    // Get all digits from the test string
    std::vector<std::string> token(std::sregex_token_iterator(test.begin(),test.end(),re, -1), {});

    // Output result
    std::copy(token.begin(), token.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout," "));

    return 0;
}
```